# How can CLLocationManager call correct delegate methods depending on iOS version

Tags: ios5, ios6, cllocationmanager

In iOS 5 , delegate method is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

where as in iOS 6 method is

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

My app supports both version. How CLLocation manage will know which method it should call ? 
Do I need to add some #if def ? If yes , can anybody tell me how can I write this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;`

You can build using iOS 6 SDK and set the deployment target to support iOS 5 as well. In case if it doesn't work, you can try implementing this method and call `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`
 inside that(You can implement this iOS 6 method as well, so that in case of iOS 6 it calls this method directly). You can create an array out of newLocation and oldLocation and pass to this. But I dont think that will be needed. You can test it out in both devices.